# Reactive Prop Input Vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-props

### Explanation

I have a parent and a child component.

The child component is created using `v-for='course in allCourses'`, cycling through an array of objects.
It receives a bool called `isSelected` via props.

The `isSelected` bool depends on if the respective course of the child component is contained in another array: `const selectedCourses = ref<Array<Object>>()`

To check for this i implemented an arrow function that looks like this:

```
const isSelected = (_courseData :any) :boolean => {
    if (selectedCourses.value?.some(e => e == _courseData)) {
        return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}
```

This i added into the prop of my child component as follows:

```
<mychildcomponent v-for="course in allCourses" :isSelected="isSelected(course)" @toggle-select="handleSelect"/>
```

### Problem

However, of course, this does not update when there are changes made to the `selectedCourses`-Array, as i do via an emit in my child component.

When the child is clicked, it emits its data if its now selected or just `false` if it's now unselected. A simple function handles this inside my parent component to either push the data to `selectedCourses` or remove it.

### Question

How do i get my `isSelected`-function to run (and therefore update the `isSelected`-prop of each child component) when this emit fires (or maybe with a hook for when `selectedCourses` is updated)?
I know i could just pass in the whole `selectedCourses` as a prop into my child component and evaluate it's state in there, however i do not want to do this to ensure prop stability.

Comment: Will `@toggle-select="handleSelect(course)"` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution goes into the direction of Dimavas proposal in his comment.

I had to do a little more though to make it fit for my needs.

```
@toggle-select="isSelected($event, true)" :isSelected='isSelected(course, false)'
```

The components emit now executes `isSelected()`. The event contains the data of the emit, also i pass in `true` as a second argument.

`isSelected` looks like this:

```
const isSelected = (_courseData :any, _update: boolean) :boolean => {
    if(_update) {
        handleSelect(_courseData)
    }
    if (selectedCourses.value?.some((e: any) => e == _courseData)) {

        return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}
```

The `_update`-Bool we passed in earlier is there to stop this solution from entering an infinite loop, as `isSelected()` is also called in the `isSelected`-prop of my component. There we pass in `false` to stop the recursion.